# Creating a new row every 4 or 5 columns in C# razor code

Tags: c#, razor

I saw a way to do this in php, but I'm using razor code.  I need to insert a close row and an open row tag every 4 loops.  But the main loop I'm using is a foreach which doesn't really give me a good variable to use mod on.  Here is what I have.  Can you give me a quick solution? I'm sure it's simple.
This is what I have:

```
  <tbody>
        <tr align="center">
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            { @for (int loops = 1; loops < 6; loops++)
                {   
                <td>
                    <img src="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PicUrl)" height="100" /><br />
                    <b>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</b><br />
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)<br />
                    <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit</a> |
                    <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Details</a> |
                    <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Delete</a>
                </td>
                }

            }
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Unfortunately, as you might imagine, this code simply puts 5 of the same photo before it loads 5 of the next photo, and all in a single row across.

Comment: Could you use @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Length; i++) instead of the foreach and then use %?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated with counter and mod

```
@{int counter = 0;}
<tbody>
    <tr align="center">
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <td>
                <img src="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PicUrl)" height="100" /><br />
                <b>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</b><br />
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)<br />
                <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit</a> |
                <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Details</a> |
                <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Delete</a>
            </td>
            counter++;
            if (counter % 5 == 0)
            {
                @:</tr><tr>
            }
        }
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I think `counter % 5` logic will need some attention to make sure it's working as expected.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, and it looks like you're on the right track, however it did not like .Length OR .Count.  Also, in your example, it didn't have a context for item.Name, item.Id or item.PicUrl because that was part of the "foreach(item in ..."

Comment: May I ask what type the Model is, maybe we can pull something out.

Comment: Yes, Saharsh. It's a simple dataset with a name, description, ID, and photo name (inserted into the url). I believe I need to establish a counter of the loops, and if mod 5 == 0 then write </td></tr><tr>, else </td>. I am just having trouble getting that nested loop into razor code.

Comment: I made changes to the answer, with a counter and mod operator. It worked with a simple List<string> model. You might need to tweak it as I wasn't able to test it with the dataset.

Comment: That did it, Saharsh!  I had been trying to initialize a variable like "@int counter = 0;" but I did not know about enclosing it in braces.  I have a lot to learn about razor coding.  Thanks!!

Comment: great! could you accept this as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know how. Haha. Let me know and I'll take care of it.